# Match range between years

Tags: sql, regex

I try to match a pattern which is year-year. For example "2019-20 ggtt", "1990-91 ggcc"  and etc.

I used function PatINDEX to look for if the pattern exists in my field, however the below pattern I created did not give me the correct result. Someone please help?

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9]^4\-[0-9]^2%', fieldName)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', fieldName)
```

[PATINDEX ( '%pattern%' , expression )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **pattern**
>
> Is a character expression that contains the sequence to be
>   found. Wildcard characters can be used; however, the % character must
>   come before and follow pattern (except when you search for first or
>   last characters). pattern is an expression of the character string
>   data type category. pattern is limited to 8000 characters.

It seems, pattern only supports Wildcard characters, not regex